# Django - A bit lost with forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm working in Django forms. I'm a bit lost with where to put code about forms (forms.py or models.py?) And which code put in my template. I searched about docs but can't figure it out, I'm a bit new in Django, thanks.

I will appreciate if somebody could gave me a complete example of a simple form to understand this stuff.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your exact problem? What can't you understand?

Comment: It's said in my question, where to place the code of the form and a basic example to see how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/%20Source)

You should create your Form classes in **forms.py**

Example

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField()
    sender = forms.EmailField()
    cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

To render the form in your template you need to add it into the context. So your **views.py** should look something like this.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        # ContactForm was defined in the the previous section
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = ContactForm() # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Notice this part. The dictionary {'form': form} is your request context which means that the keys will be added to your template variables.

```
return render(request, 'contact.html', {
    'form': form,
})
```

Now, you can use it in your templates.

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Updated the answer.

Comment: Just what I wanted, thanks !

Comment: I tried but I've a little problem, When I want to access to the form, it automatically redirects me to the contact.html and I've already set the proper validations:

        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass

                subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']

                message = form.cleaned_data['message']

                sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']

                cc_myself = form.cleaned_data['cc_myself']

Comment: You should probably remove the action="/contact/" part in your template.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a Look at **this Basic Sample, provided in following link,** for Handling a POST form in django.

http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-use-python-django-forms/